How do I return a nested object array using a Signal in Angular/Typescript?
In my Angular/Typescript code, I have a nested object array that I am trying to return(filter) based on the object property which has the value === 'event'.
I don't know what I'm missing but for some reason, it won't return the nested object array but instead keeps telling me my variable is of type CalendarModel[] which is the parent.
I added :{types} to the variables/filters to show you what Angular tells me the variable types are.
getAllEvents: Signal<CalendarModel[]> = computed(() => this.dataService.allInformation()?.allCalendarInformation?.filter(calendar: CalendarModel => calendar?.events?.filter(event: CalendarEvent=> event.type === 'event').filter(event: CalendarEvent => {
    return new Date(event.date).getTime() >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }))
);

Here is my model structure:
allCalendarInformation: CalendarModel[];

export interface CalendarModel {
  date: Date;
  events: CalendarEvent[];
}

export interface CalendarEvent {
  imageUrl?: string
  title: string;
  date?: Date;
  location?: string;
  time?: string;
  description: string;
  type?: string;
  featured?: boolean;
}

Am I missing something?
I'm drilling down into events and trying to get all the events that have the type === 'event' but Typescript keeps telling me my overall object from getAllEvents is of type CalendarModel[]. Shouldn't it be CalendarEvent[]?
Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.
I have multiple other filtered objects throughout my project and they work but I'm doing something wrong here.

What is your expectations ?


Iterate all CalendarModel objects and combine the CalendarEvent into an array via .reduce().

Filter the CalendarEvent object by type and date.


getAllEvents: Signal<CalendarEvent[]> = computed(() =>
  this.dataService.allInformation()
    ?.allCalendarInformation
    ?.reduce(
      (acc: CalendarEvent[], cur: CalendarModel) => [...acc, ...cur.events],
      [] as CalendarEvent[]
    )
    .filter(
      (event: CalendarEvent) =>
        event.type === 'event' &&
        event.date &&
        new Date(event.date).getTime() >= new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    ))
);

Demo @ StackBlitz

I am not near my computer until tomorrow but I will check this solution! I'll have to dive into the reduce method..

Thank you so much! I realize with this answer I have some cleaning of code to do haha. I appreciate your quick response!

This is because the filter method is operating on top of CalendarModel which is an array array. You have to apply some reducer or map and make this array have a single dimension.
Then, once you have this single array, you can filter the object by the type property.
